# How to write a Bash script that accepts options?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script

I'm writing a Bash script to make easier to start a local webserver that I use for testing purposes; I don't need it running all the time, it is more useful to me to start it when I need it.

Right now I need to run the following two commands to start it

```
sudo systemctl start apache2  
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

and these to stop it

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2  
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

To make it easier, I wrote a simple Bash script, `webserver-start`, to start it:

```
#!/bin/bash

#starts the webserver

sudo systemctl start apache2  
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

And a similar one to stop it.

I'd like to put everything in a single script file, and use some options to select if I want to start or stop (or even restart) the webserver, something in this fashion: `webserver -s` to start, `webserver -p` to stop, and so on.

How can I modify my scripts to make them accept different options and perform a different task based on them?

Comment: technically speaking, those are Arguments, not Options. Options start with - or -- per POSIX. http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Pass-Arguments-To-A-Bash-Script.htm Also, you appear to be wanting to write an LSB init script, so see here: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is the following:

`web.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl $1 apache2 mysql
```

The benefit of this solution is that you can do the following:

- `sudo ./web.sh start` to start everything.
- `sudo ./web.sh stop` to stop everything.
- `sudo ./web.sh restart` to restart.
- And so on...